# How can I truncate lines in org-mode buffers?

Tags: org-mode

I'm unable to make org-mode buffers truncate lines by default.

This is my entire init.el

```
(setq-default truncate-lines t)
```

I launch Emacs

```
emacs -nw test.org
```

, but it won't start up with lines truncated.

I have to

```
(toggle-truncate-lines)
```

I've found references to

```
;org-mode truncate-lines
(setq org-startup-truncated t)
```

, but this has no effect.

Any pointers as to what I can try?;)

EDIT: That's so weird that it works for you.

```
[b0ef@spartacus:~]$ cat .emacs.d/init.el
(setq-default truncate-lines t)
```

```
[b0ef@spartacus:~]$ emacs -nw -q -l ~/.emacs.d/init.el data/test/test.org
```

```
[b0ef@spartacus:~]$ cat data/test/test.org
* test

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.  Donec hendrerit tempor tellus.  Donec pretium posuere tellus.  Proin quam nisl, tincidunt et, mattis eget, convallis nec, purus.  Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus.  Nulla posuere.  Donec vitae dolor.  Nullam tristique diam non turpis.  Cras placerat accumsan nulla.  Nullam rutrum.  Nam vestibulum accumsan nisl.

** level 1
*** level 1.1

** level 2
*** level 2.1
```

```
truncate-lines is a variable defined in ‘C source code’.

Its value is t
Original value was nil
Local in buffer test.org; global value is the same.

Non-nil means do not display continuation lines.
Instead, give each line of text just one screen line.

Note that this is overridden by the variable
‘truncate-partial-width-windows’ if that variable is non-nil
and this buffer is not full-frame width.

Minibuffers set this variable to nil.

Don’t set this to a non-nil value when ‘visual-line-mode’ is
turned on, as it could produce confusing results.

  Automatically becomes permanently buffer-local when set.
  Calls these functions when changed: (#<subr set-buffer-redisplay>)
  This variable is safe as a file local variable if its value
  satisfies the predicate ‘booleanp’.
  You can customize this variable.
  Probably introduced at or before Emacs version 1.7.
```

EDIT: I see now that I might have written this question wrong. The question is how I can have long lines continue on the next line.

```
[b0ef@spartacus:~]$ cat .emacs.d/init.el
(setq-default truncate-lines nil)
```

, but when I start up and look at C-h v truncate-lines, it's still true.

EDIT: Ok, now it works

```
[b0ef@spartacus:~]$ cat .emacs.d/init.el
(setq-default truncate-lines nil)
;org-mode truncate-lines
(setq org-startup-truncated nil)
```

Thanks and sorry for the confusion and noise. Maybe I should edit this whole question?;)

Comment: Works for me. Are you sure you are using the correct init file? Try `emacs -nw -q -l /tmp/foo.el test.org` where `foo.el` has only the `setq-default` above. And check the value of `truncate-lines` with `C-h v`.

Comment: "Thanks and sorry for the confusion and noise. Maybe I should edit this whole question?" - or you might choose to delete it, given that it was just a misunderstanding.